# Evaluate $\int \frac{(1 + e^x)^2}{e^x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am struggling with this integral: $$\int \frac{(1 + e^x)^2}{e^x} dx$$

I tried u substitution setting u = 1+ e^x but that was not fruitful. I also tried expanding $(1+e^x)^2$ and got $1 + 2e^x + e^{2x}$. I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please show what you have tried so far? Have you tried expanding the expression $(1 + e^{x})^{2}$ and use the fact that $(e^{x})' = e^{x}$?

Comment: I tried u substitution setting u = 1+ e^x but that was not fruitful. I also tried expanding (1+e^x)^2 and got 1 + 2e^x + e^2x. I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Please add these comments to your question

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that $(1 + e^{x})^{2} = 1 + 2e^{x} + e^{2x}$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{(1+e^{x})^{2}}{e^{x}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{1 + 2e^{x} + e^{2x}}{e^{x}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int(e^{-x} + 2 + e^{x})\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = -e^{-x} + 2x + e^{x} + c
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Comment: Thank you! I was literally one step away from the answer.

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad to help.